# Pinterest images from opengraph not showing?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, pinterest

I've added two images as `<meta property="og:image" content="URL" />` to my head section.

However, when clicking the pinterest extension button, it does not show these images. Does pinterest only show images that are actually embedded in the body of the page? Is there any way to get the `open graph` images also showing?

Comment: Have you used the full domain to your image? content="/bla/image.jpg" wont work

Answer (score -1):

I think that in a usual code you can load only the images embedded in  tag.
Please let us know why you want to be able to pin images that are not visible on the page, and maybe someone can help you